# How to create a Friend Request system with mongoDB and Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my social media application, I want to introduce a friend request system that is similar to Instagram:

- user A can follow user B, but user B doesn't have to follow user A back
- if user B is a private user, then user B should receive a follow request from user A which they can either approve or decline. On approval, user A is registered as a follower of user B

How could this be achieved using mongoDB (including Mongoose) and Express?

I currently have some simple `User`, `UserFollower` and `UserFollowing` schemas that allow simple follow/unfollow updates to take place. They are configured as below:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  // isPrivate: Boolean,
});

const userFollowerSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  followerIds: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
});

const userFollowingSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  followingIds: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
});
```

At the moment, user A is able to follow user B freely, with their ID getting added to user B's `followerIds` on demand. However, as per the commented path, I want a permission to be granted from user B if their `isPrivate` => `true`.

Obviously, this is quite a basic implementation so far, but I'm happy to restructure it completely to make it more scalable to include features such as blocking users etc.

Comment: your need another table for requests, place both user ids in it i.e user_a, user_b and the status 0 being request, 1 being accepted, 2 being rejected etc, user a is the requester user b is the target, user_a sees it a pending request and b needs action the request.. just plopping ids in an array wont work.

Comment: Hi @LawrenceCherone, thanks for the response. 

Given what you're saying, if `user_b` accepts the request, should I then add `user_a`'s ID to to `user_b`'s `followerIds` and `user_b`'s ID to `user_a`'s `followingIds`?

Comment: Also @LawrenceCherone, I want to query any given user's relationships at any given time. For example, on the client, `user_c` might visit `user_d`'s profile page and `user_c` should be able to see all of `user_d`'s followers, while also seeing *their own relationship* `status` *with those followers* e.g. `'following'`, `'not following'`, `'requested'`. How could I go about this? Is a joins of each `Followers` and `FollowRequests` table avoidable in this scenario? Thanks